# Reconverting a list from pandas.read_html into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on processing an HTML page and translating its data into RDF. I load the html tabular data into a dataframe and am now trying to replace the blank spaces with underscores. I get this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

At some point, the dataframe is being converted into a list. Why is this happening? What can I do to get back the dataframe?

This is the code:

```
#Parsing data from website
Immunization_Coverage_Data_url = 'http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/timeseries/tswucoveragebcg.html'

#Adding website data to dataframe. Matching by year identifies the specific table of interest
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.read_html(Immunization_Coverage_Data_url, match='2014', flavor='bs4', header=0, index_col=None, skiprows=0, attrs=None, parse_dates=False, tupleize_cols=False, thousands=', ', encoding=None)
#print df1

    # Preparing URIs
    url = 'http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/timeseries/tswucoveragebcg/'
    url_start = '<'
    url_end = '>'
    DBpedia_resource_url = 'http://dbpedia.org/page/'

    #Cleaning data in the dataframe
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    #df1.replace(to_replace=' ', value='_', inplace=True, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad', axis=None)
    df1[df1.replace({' ': '_'}, regex=True)]
    print df1
```

UPDATE 1

Does it make sense to reconvert the list created into a dataframe? If yes, how does one do it?

UPDATE 2

```
If I add the following:

df2 = pd.concat(df1)
df2.replace(r' ', '_', regex=True)
print df2
```

I get the following error:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  mask = arr == x
```

Comment: well according to the [pandas.read_html documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html), it is supposed to return a list

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked at the documentation more closely. I need to figure out if I can reconvert the list into a dataframe. Updating the question accordingly.

Comment: it does return a list of data frames so you just need to iterate through the dataframes and call replace on your iterations